# NodeJS TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined while accessing cloudant

Tags: node.js, rest, cloudant

I am trying to get a basic understanding of how CRUD operations with db  works with node js.
I have created two separate files - server.js and app.js.
server.js contains code for accessing the database and app.js got a reference to server.js through 'require'.
Below is my code for server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var port = process.env.PORT || 8999;
var router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use('/cloudApi', router);
app.listen(port);
console.log('REST API is runnning at ' + port);

var dbp = "users";
var Users;

function initCloudant() {
    var cloudantURL = appEnv.services.cloudantNoSQLDB[0].credentials.url || appEnv.getServiceCreds("users-cloudant").url;
    var Cloudant = require('cloudant')({
      url: cloudantURL,
      plugin: 'retry',
      retryAttempts: 10,
      retryTimeout: 500
    });

    Users = Cloudant.use(dbp);
}

router.route('/tests').get(function (req, res) {
    console.log("Inside tests api");
    Users.find({
        selector: {
            "testName":"abc"
        },
    }, function(err, result) {
       res.send(result);


    });
    });
```

when I run this using command : node server.js, everything works fine for me.
I can access the api through postman as well.

in my app.js, I have given refernce to this:

```
var server= require('./dir/server.js');
```

when I run the command- node app.js 
and try to hit the api, I get error as :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at C:\Users\nodeApp\dir\server.js:80:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:
95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:
95:5)
    at C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\nodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\anodeApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

I dont know what point I am missing so that the apis can work.

Answer (score 1):

Your initCloudant method is never getting executed it seems.

call initCloudant from success callback of get method like below:

```
router.route('/tests').get(function (req, res) { 

    initCloudant() //call it here

    console.log("Inside tests api");
    Users.find({
        selector: {
            "testName":"abc"
        },
    }, function(err, result) {
       res.send(result);


 });
```

Or alternatively intialize your User object properly to default properties.

Comment: Hi PraJazz. Thanks for your answer but it still not working. Now its complaining for "cannot read property 0" and if I remove that line, then "cannot read property 'url'" . If I run this file individually, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you post your updated code in full along with the full error message?